# Why is there a delay when i press the JFXButton that connects me to a SQL Server 2012 database and does a specific query, and just for the first time?

Tags: java, javafx, jdbc, prepared-statement

this is a small java program login sample i've done, when i run it and press on the JFXButton Login, a delay for about 1 second happen, shown in the image, knowing that the program succeeds in connecting and querying after that delay

[this happens to the JFXButton for the second delay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhuNL.png)

afterwards, when i press on that button again, it runs fast and smoothly until i stop and run again.

note that the signup JFXButton which takes me to another scene works fine, and that i am new to this field. Thank you :)

```
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        progressBar.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
        progressBar.setVisible(false);
        wrngPassLbl.setVisible(false);
        handler = new DBHandler();
    }

    @FXML
    public void loginAction(ActionEvent e) {

        progressBar.setVisible(true);
        PauseTransition pt = new PauseTransition();
        pt.setDuration(Duration.seconds(3));
        pt.setOnFinished(ex -> {
            System.out.println("Login successful.");

        });
        pt.play();

        String q1 = "select * from [User] where userName=? and userPass=?";
        dbConnection = handler.getConnection();

        try {
            pst = dbConnection.prepareStatement(q1);
            pst.setString(1, usrTxt.getText());
            pst.setString(2, passTxt.getText());
            ResultSet result = pst.executeQuery();

            int count = 0;
            while (result.next()) {
                count++;
            }

            if (count == 1) {
                System.out.print("Connection is successfully established");

            } else if (count == 0) {
                System.out.print("wrong username or password");
            }
            pst.close();
            dbConnection.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

and this is the DBHanler class (for the connection)

```
public class DBHandler extends Configs {

    Connection dbConnection;

    public Connection getConnection() {

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.setProperty("user", dbUser);
        prop.setProperty("password", dbPass);
        prop.setProperty("useSSL", "false");
        prop.setProperty("autoReconnect", "true");

        String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://" + dbHost + ":" + dbPort + "/" + dbName;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString,prop);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dbConnection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question itself, but a SQL statement of `"select * from [User] where userName=? and userPass=?"` **strongly**suggests you're storing plain text passwords in your database. I *hope* that's not the case, and that `userPass` is actually a hashed version of the password, using a Salt.

Comment: I would guess that the first time it runs the SQL Engine needs to fill the buffer cache, which takes a second. For each subsequent run the cache is already filled, so the query runs a lot quicker. Based on the connection string you create I am guessing you are using MySQL - you can read more about the buffer pool here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html

Comment: You're executing this JDBC code on the _JavaFX Application Thread_. The FX thread is responsible for updating UI state and scheduling render "pulses", which means it can't do any of that while it's busy doing something else, hence the UI freezing. Do the work on a background thread and publish the result, if any, back to the FX thread—see [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm).

Comment: @Larnu this program is for personal education, and i am still in the beginning, so userPass is not yet a hashed version of the password. But i will definitely do it. Thank you

Comment: Also, as you mentioned you're learning, check out the [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: Thanks for your efforts all, will check everything out.

Comment: @Slaw my problem was fixed using your solution.

Comment: Your JDBC URL and driver are for **MySQL**, not for SQL Server - those are two very different database products. And the MySQL driver can not connect to SQL Server.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ohh, that's because i copied the wrong class...  im working on two similar projects, one connected to mysql and the other to ssms, and they both have DBHandler class it actually is ```jdbc:sqlserver://....```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was fixed using [Concurrency in javaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm) as @Slaw suggested